# Rails way to do group(column) having count(id) > 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

What is the "rails way" to do the following (postgres):

```
PurchaseOrder.connection.exec_query('select po_number, count(id) as count_id from purchase_orders group by po_number having count(id) > 1')
```

What I obviously want to do is find the duplicate po_numbers.

```
PurchaseOrder.select(:id, :po_number, count(id)).group(:po_number).having('count(id) > 1')
```

and various random variations does not work ->

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column
>   "purchase_orders.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in
>   an aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could do something like mentioned below:

```
PurchaseOrder.select("po_number, count(id)").group("po_number").having('count(*) > 1').size
```